# Where can I find project repositories with continuous testing?

Tags: logging, repository, integration, testing, continuous

I am interested in studying some test logs from different projects, in order to build and test an application for school. I need to analyze the parts of the code which are tested, the bugs which appeared in those parts and eventually how they were resolved.

But for this I need some repositories from different (open source) projects. Can someone please help me with ideas or links or any kind of test logs which might be useful? I really need some resources, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you wrote it, but in case you're still interested in learning more about this or someone else comes across this answer, I've been writing this automation tool which might be helpful for you:

http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/

It's in Mercurial, so you can look at the mercurial logs. You can also get an idea of when I fixed bugs, diff to see what I changed, etc.

Everything *ought* to be tested, with scenarios that pretend to be testing a Pet Shop (the real code I'm testing is actually the automation tool), and unit tests in NUnit.

Pretty much when I have a bug, I either write a scenario then a unit test, or a unit test on its own if it's not really appropriate for a scenario.

You can also see closed bugs in the "Issues". There are a couple which I decided were bugs in other libraries, outside of my scope, or I'd created work arounds which I preferred so I wasn't going to fix.